# Chart.js Show Dollar Amount On Left Y And Percent Amount On Right Y

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am running the below syntax which displays my combo chart as it should.  However, the issue that I am running into is that the array values contains $ amounts and is displayed on the left side of the Y axis, the array values1 contains % amounts and is always sitting on thet bottom since $'s are always higher than %'side

My thought was is it possible to display $ amounts on the left side of the Y axis, and % amounts on the right side of the Y Axis and have Line Data map to the %'s and have Bar Data map to the $'s

This is my current syntax:

```
var labelsarr = ['George 11', 'George 12', 'Fred 11', 'Fred 12', 'Sage 11', 'Sage 12'];
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: labelsarr,
        datasets: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                fill: false,
                label: 'Line Data',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                data: values1
            },
            {
                label: 'Bar Data',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 129, 214, 0.8)',
                data: values
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (t, d) {
                    if (t.datasetIndex === 0) {
                        var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                        var yLabel = t.yLabel + '%';
                        return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                    } else if (t.datasetIndex === 1) {
                        var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                        var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') : '$' + t.yLabel;
                        return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                            return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
                        } else {
                            return '$' + value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    plugins: [{
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var labels = chart.data.labels;
            labels.forEach(function (e, i) {
                var bar = chart.data.datasets[1]._meta[0].data[i]._model;
                var dataPoint = e.split(/\s/)[1];
                if (dataPoint === '16')
                    bar.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                else if (dataPoint === '17')
                    bar.backgroundColor = 'green';
            });
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

set **`yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'`** for your first dataset, like so :

```
...
datasets: [{
   type: 'line',
   fill: false,
   label: 'Line Data',
   backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
   borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
   data: [3, 4, 10, 5, 8, 7],
   yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' //<- set this
}, {
   ...
}]
...
```

<sup>this is to map the dataset to right y-axis</sup>

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

add another y-axis *(for percent amount)* to the **`yAxes`** array, as such :

```
...
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
      ...
   }, {
      id: 'y-axis-1',
      position: 'right',
      ticks: {
         beginAtZero: true,
         callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return value + '%';
         }
      }
   }]
}
...
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var labelsarr = ["George 11", "George 12", "Fred 11", "Fred 12", "Sage 11", "Sage 12"];
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: labelsarr,
      datasets: [{
         type: 'line',
         fill: false,
         label: 'Line Data',
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
         data: [3, 4, 10, 5, 8, 7],
         yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'

      }, {
         label: 'Bar Data',
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 129, 214, 0.8)',
         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               if (t.datasetIndex === 0) {
                  var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                  var yLabel = t.yLabel + '%';
                  return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
               } else if (t.datasetIndex === 1) {
                  var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                  var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
                  return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
               }
            }
         }
      },
      legend: {
         display: false,
         position: 'top',
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                     return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                  } else {
                     return '$' + value;
                  }
               }
            }
         }, {
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            position: 'right',
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  return value + '%';
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   },
   plugins: [{
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
         var labels = chart.data.labels;
         labels.forEach(function(e, i) {
            var bar = chart.data.datasets[1]._meta[0].data[i]._model;
            var dataPoint = e.split(/\s/)[1];
            if (dataPoint === '16')
               bar.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            else if (dataPoint === '17')
               bar.backgroundColor = 'green';
         });
      }
   }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```